# How to add specific folder to java classpath in web project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have different folders for properties file in my project structure.

Like an example I have three folders created in class path under `src` folder of my project as say a,b,c where inside these folders contains different properties files.

**When I read file from this folder I read as /a/someFile.properties**.

So, what I want is, I want one main folder called properties to be created under SRC folder of my project where all the a,b,c folders should be sub-folders of the main properties folder. **When I read the file from java code I should read  as /a/someFile.properties only**.

Is there any solution to add properties folder to server class path, so that I don't need to prefix properties folder while reading file.

Thanks,
Prathap

Answer (score 0):

If you want the properties files to be in your main source folder, then the package tree must match with the folder tree (which is a good thing, because it makes things much simpler), and you must thus have a, b and c as direct subfolders of the source folder.

If you want to put the properties file in a different folder, you must create a new source folder in Eclipse (named "properties", for example), outside of the main source folder. Right-click the project, select *New*, and the *Source Folder*.

Comment: Hi, Let me clarify clearly: As said i have three folders under src folder as a,b,c which contains different files. When i read the file from a i should refer as a/someFile.txt . To make clear i will create one more folder called data inside this data folder i move all those a,b,c folders. So as per me when i read file from a folder i should refer as data/a/someFile.txt which i dont want to include data as prefix. Actually in my weblogic server there is already data folder added to server classpath.

Comment: If you want to refer them as /a/file.properties, then you must not put them in a data folder under the source folder. That's how it is. Why do you want this data folder? It's like you wanted to have a chocolate ice cream but keep buying strawberry. If you want chocolate, buy chocolate.

Comment: Hi, Why i need this requirement is ,In Dev, my application runs in web-logic server 10g under UNIX machine , in web-logic domain they have added "data" folder to web-logic server class-path so that what ever properties folder like a,b,c will be placed directly under "data" folder this acts as a class-path..when i read file from java code in web-logic server i refer as /a/someFile.txt which works perfectly and there is no need of "data" to be prefix. Let me know if i should clearly specify requirement.

Comment: Then, use a different source folder for your properties file, and have your build script for the unix deployment copy the contents of the data source folder to the data unix directory, and compile and create a war from the main source folder. You may have two source folders in Eclipse, but in each one, the package structure must match the directory structure.

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you. I am not clear about your solution.What is the purpose of using different source folder?

Comment: To be able to easily distinguish what must go to the war file, and what must go to the data unix directory. Isn't it what your question is all about?